# RESTEasy + Spring 3 + Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, service, resteasy

I'm having some issues trying to configure an app to use RESTEasy + Spring 3 + Maven. So far this is what I have:

Service interface:

```
package com.test.service;
public interface ProcessRequestService {
    String test();
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
package com.test.service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProcessRequestServiceImpl implements ProcessRequestService {
    @Override
    public String test() {
        return "Resteasy Test";
    }
}
```

Component:

```
package com.test.web;

@Component
@Path("/message")
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessRequestService processRequestService;

    public void setService(ProcessRequestService processRequestService) {
        this.processRequestService = processRequestService;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/example")
    public Response example() {
        String result = processRequestService.test();
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <resteasy.version>3.0.4.Final</resteasy.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>client</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/api</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

And finally mvc-dispatcher.servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

What I'm trying to avoid is to declare many beans in an xml file by using the @Service annotation.

When I deploy this application to jboss 6.1 I get a NullPointerException. I guess it is because Spring is not able to Autowire the service to the Component but I'm not sure why this is happening.

I was able to achieve this by making some modifications to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/) tutorial but it is using Spring's RequestMapping instead of RESTEasy.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use Apache CXF implementation of JAX-RS which supports Spring. There probably will not be any code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.please try this.

In POM file add the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
<version>3.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And in mvc-dispatcher.servlet.xml add the bean definition above component-scan

```
<bean class="org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessorServletAware"/>
```

This will solve the null pointer exception.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **What I'm trying to avoid is to declare many beans in an xml file b**y
>   **using the @Service annotation**

What you are doing is fine. Mapping from annotations instead of XML is not what is giving you the `NullPointerException`.

> **When I deploy this application to jboss 6.1 I get a**
>   **NullPointerException. I guess it is because Spring is not able to**
>   **Autowire the service to the Component but I'm not sure why this is**
>   **happening**

Yes, JBoss is not able to inject because JAX-RS (in your case RESTEasy) does not know about Spring beans. They are not integrated out of the box.

It is happening because the JAX-RS implementation wont look from `@Autowired` in its resources (resources in this context are `@Path` annotated classes).

You need extra work for using Spring Beans inside a Java EE container.

> **Any help will be appreciated**

All the options you have that I could find are:

- [Get your Spring Bean from an ApplicationContext](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-spring-integration-example/)
- [Use `@Inject` convention](http://blog.comsysto.com/2012/08/02/resteasy-integration-with-spring-tutorial-part-1-introduction/) (I think it is not supported for JBoss 6, not sure)
- [Declare your RESTful API with Java Interfaces](http://esofthead.com/restful-application-spring-resteasy/)

I didnt test these examples btw. Another options are:

- Just go with Spring MVC as you mentioned.
- Use EJB instead of Spring Beans, which would make sense since you are under a Java EE server.
- Maybe try Jersey.

Keep in mind that Spring's Transaction is independant from Java EE transaction. You are mixing JAX-RS with Spring. Transaction will need extra love.

If I were you I would consider using EJB instead of Spring Beans if it is an option.

> **I'm having some issues trying to configure an app to use RESTEasy +**
>   **Spring 3 + Maven**

Check out another answer of mine about this topic. Maybe it will help you decide which engine of RESTful is more appropriate for your solution.

[Spring annotations for GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794936/spring-annotations-for-get-requests/23796415#23796415)